# can i add include v-if , v-for ,v-bind for a same class in vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

i have a doubt , i need to  add v-bind and v-for to same class is that possible in vue.js?

```
    <div class="printIconSection"   v-for="report in reports" :key="report.property" >
        <div class="printIcon" id="printReport_AId" v-if="isOverview">
         <font-awesome-icon :icon="report.icon" @click="printWindow()"/>
        </div>
      </div>
```

i need to add v-bind:class="{ 'title-long' : changeTitle }"  to the printIconSection class .

how can combine ?is that recommended ?

Comment: It is not clear please add more info ?

Answer (score 0):

```html
   <div
      v-for="report in reports"
      :key="report.property"
      :class="['printIconSection', { 'title-long' : changeTitle }]">

      <div class="printIcon" id="printReport_AId" v-if="isOverview">
       <font-awesome-icon :icon="report.icon" @click="printWindow()"/>
      </div>

    </div>
```

Try doing this.
I hope it helps